# Phillips Hue lights return to full brightness seconds after dimming. No power cut

Tags: smart-lights, philips-hue

I have multiple Phillips hue light bulbs - the white ambiance 1100 model. I am using a model 2.1 bridge. Whenever I attempt to dim them, they do respond, and then about two seconds later, return to full brightness. This happens whether i dim all of the lights, or just one. It happens across multiple fixtures etc. and is not a power issue. I have attempted power cycling the bridge and lights as well as re-linking the lights.

Has anyone had this problem? What steps can I take to resolve it?

Comment: I've had that problem ... solved by returning lamps to the store

Comment: Do you maybe have a scenario set up that would do this? Or maybe they are linked to a motion sensor? Are all the lights involved in the same room or different rooms?

Comment: My guess: The brightness control is allowed only via a certain path. You're trying to directly go to the bulbs and cut out the "middleman" controller in the path. Figure out how to request the controller to change the brightness. Just a guess as I said.